# How to retrieve error from stored procedure in oracle using php?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to make a simple car rental system with one of the tables: car

```
CREATE TABLE "WILSON"."CAR" 
(   "CAR_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CAR_PLATE" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CAR_MODEL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "CAR_COLOR" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "CAR_STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "CAR_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "CAR_STATUS_CHK" CHECK (CAR_STATUS IN ('AVAILABLE','NOT AVAILABLE','MAINTENANCE')) ENABLE, 
         PRIMARY KEY ("CAR_ID"),
         CONSTRAINT "CAR_UNIQUE" UNIQUE ("CAR_PLATE", "CAR_MODEL", "CAR_COLOR")
);
```

with a stored procedure to insert a new car:

```
create or replace procedure insert_car_proc(plateno varchar2, car_model varchar2, color varchar2, cate_id varchar2)
is
begin
      insert into car(car_plate, car_model, car_color, car_category) values (plateno, car_model, color, cate_id);
end;



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $plateno = $_POST['platenoInput'];
    $model = $_POST['modelInput'];
    $color = $_POST['colorInput'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

//    var_dump($plateno, $model, $color, $category);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('begin insert_car_proc(?,?,?,?); end;');
    try{
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $plateno);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $model);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $color);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $category);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'success';
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It's able to insert new car, but as i have the constraint of 3 columns (car_color, car_plate, car_model) i want to retrieve the error using php to show user about **'Same car existed.Please check again.'** how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution. I used the following code with PDOExeception::errorInfo:

```
catch(PDOException $e){
        if($e->errorInfo[1] == '1'){
            echo 'Duplicated Car Inserted';
        }
    }
```

the `$e->errorInfo[1] == '1'` needs to check the error code from oracle.